# android : play short sound with short evoluting period using SoundPool

Tags: android, performance, loops, soundpool

I want to implement a sort of radar we can find on cars to help parking. On a service that is correctly connected to my activity by a binder, I start a thread that must repeat a short sound.wav (110ms long) with a short period that will change. 
With this code, at the beginning the first loop plays the sound but has difficulties and quickly lose the rythm. Worst, the service will never stop. The garbage collector is saturated.
I didn't find the way to properly realise this.
THX

```
        public class MainService extends Service implements OnLoadCompleteListener{
            private boolean soundradarloaded;
            private SoundPool spoolradar;
            private int soundradarID;
            private Thread timerThread;
            private boolean timerThreadrunning;

            public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
                soundradarloaded=false;
                spoolradar = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
                soundradarID = spoolradar.load(this, R.raw.beepradar1, 1);
                spoolradar.setOnLoadCompleteListener(this);
                timerThreadrunning=true;
                timerThread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    int counter=0;
                    long offset=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while(timerThreadrunning) {
                        // Traitement
                        longtime=System.currentTimeMillis()-offset;
                        if(soundradarloaded && longtime%400==0){//play every 400ms
                            spoolradar.play(soundradarID, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
                        }
                        try {
                           Thread.sleep(1); 
                       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }

                    }
            });

            timerThread.start();
        }

    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

                if(arg0==spoolradar)
                    soundradarloaded=true;

    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        timerThreadrunning=false;
        try{
                Thread.sleep(1); 
             }catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
        spoolradar.release(soundradarID);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Precision of Thread.sleep() isn't guaranteed. If Thread.sleep(1) is ignored then the line

`if(soundradarloaded && longtime%400==0){//play every 400ms`

may be executed multiple times during the same millisecond and multiple audio streams are played at nearly the same time (or at an undesired time later). Second problem is that timerThread is running and using CPU (and battery) all the time.

Look at https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html or maybe https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html for a better solution.